# tsqlt unit tests copied to a new database

Tags: sql-server, tsqlt

Test Procedure: (Error)

> An invalid parameter or option was specified for procedure 'sp_addextendedproperty'.[16,2]{sp_addextendedproperty,37} (There was also a ROLLBACK ERROR --> The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.{Private_RunTest,160})

I'm tearing my hair out with this one. We've copied the unit tests to a brand new database but every test which fakes a table comes up with this error. Narrowed it down to proc [tSQLt].[Private_MarkFakeTable].

It *looks* like the following lines return NULL? To be clear, this works fine on other databases so it must be something to to do with the dtaabase rather than the proc.

```
DECLARE @UnquotedSchemaName NVARCHAR(MAX);SET @UnquotedSchemaName = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@SchemaName+'.'+@TableName));
   DECLARE @UnquotedTableName NVARCHAR(MAX);SET @UnquotedTableName = OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID(@SchemaName+'.'+@TableName));
```

Comment: What is the compatibility level of the database? Did you try to run the tSQLt install script?

Comment: Your error says there is invalid parameter or option specified for procedure 'sp_addextendedproperty' so show us what you are passing in

Comment: I had that when I was faking synonyms, not the actual tables.